# If we consider a model of stock price where the prices at time $t=1,2$ are $S(t,\omega)=S(0)(\frac{1}{2}+t\omega), \omega\in\Omega=[0,1]$

Tags: probability, self-study, distributions, random-variable

> **If we consider a model of stock price **

where the prices at time $t=1,2$ are

$S(t,\omega)=S(0)(\frac{1}{2}+t\omega), \omega\in\Omega=[0,1]$.
[please click here for the figure of $S_1,S_2$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6bmu.png)

A derivative security pays $\max\{0,K-S(2,\omega)\}$,

only if $S(1,\omega)\ge B$ where $K, B$ are arbitrary real numbers such that $K$ belongs to the range of $S(2)$ and $B$ belongs to the range of $S(1)$.

Find the **formula for the expectation** of the ***payoff***.

---

For Starters, we can substitue the value of $S(2,\omega)$ into the pay off function.
Expectation can be computed using: $\mathbb{E}(X)=\int_{0}^{1}X(\omega)d\omega $
1) Find the Range of $S_1$ and $S_2$

2) As $K\in$$S_2$ and $B\in$$S_1$, we can use the value of $K$ while finding the expectation
3) Finally, we can use the expectation formula, the one above, to find the same.
However, the question seems to specifically ask us to find the
**Expectation Formula**

Comment: Please add the `self-study` tag as this is clearly some kind of homework.

Comment: Added. Though this is not a homework since I am a graduate. This belongs to the realm of Call Option pricing and payoff